# Limit of $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1+\sqrt[3]{x})(\sin x -. x)}{(\cos x-1)^3 x^2}$ without hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am struggling to make this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1+\sqrt[3]{x})(\sin x - x)}{(\cos x-1)^3x^2}$$
I know it doesn't exist, and I am really near to prove it but something is blocking me. Skipping some step, I have that $$\frac{\sqrt[3]x(\sin x-x)}{-\frac{1}{2}x^8}$$
From this, I see that $x^8$ could be $x^7$, by making the top term (1-1), and from this I see that this goes to +-infinity, so it doesn't exist. But this isn't a formal method, nor probably a method at all. Would love to see your methods to solve this without hopital!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $\varepsilon>0$ and for all $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
(1-\varepsilon)\sqrt[3]{x}&\le\ln(1+\sqrt[3]{x})\\
-\varepsilon x&\le\sin(x)-x\\
\varepsilon x^2&\ge\cos(x)-1.
\end{align*}
$$
Thus for $c=\frac{\varepsilon^2-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^3}$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{c}{x^{20/3}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{((1-\varepsilon)\sqrt[3]{x})(-\varepsilon x)}{(\varepsilon x^2)^3x^2}\le\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt[3]{x})(\sin(x)-x))}{(\cos(x)-1)^3x^2}.
$$
It is easily seen that the LHS diverges as $x\to 0$ which forces the RHS to diverge as well.

Comment: You opened my mind to a new world that I already knew but now, with your way to solve, I really feel as true. I'm used to < in series, but in limits the squeeze way was something so "external". Really, this method is the fastest.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Just rewrite it as

$$\frac{\ln (1+\sqrt[3]{x})}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\sqrt[3]{x}\frac{\sin x -x}{x^3}x^3\frac{x^6}{(\cos x-1)^3}\frac{1}{x^6}\frac{1}{x^2}$$ you get a limit of $\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how to deal with $(sinx-x)$, neither in your way

Comment: @L.Repetti (sinx)/x tends to 1 as x tends to 0, have you covered this identity?

Comment: Sure, but I have $x-x$ or $1-1$!

Comment: $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\to \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for the explanation, but I don't get why; is this a known limit, or should I use some properties? EDIT: Is it because sin x is smaller than x so we can "trow it away" and keep x?

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\to \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: @alans yeah I know I couldnt edit my comment glad you cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ about $0$ which is

$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} ...$

with which you'll get

$\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}(- \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} ...)}{\frac{-1}{2}x^8}$. You can follow from here.

Comment: We still don't "know" Taylor at university, and we can use just what we have done  so I should figure out another way; anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*A general comment...*

Even though you are not allowed to use l'H$\hat{\operatorname{o}}$pital's, I do believe you may use things like the definition of derivative, product and quotient rule for limits .

For example
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{\sin x} =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\log(1+x)-\log(0)}{x}}{\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x}} =\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\log(1+x)\big|_{x=0}}{\frac{d}{dx}\sin x\big|_{x=0}}=\frac{1/(1+0)}{\cos 0}=1$$

Comment: We can use just we  have seen / demostrated, and (in university) we haven't a clue about what derivatives are, so unfortunately we can't use them!